# How can I use the uniform norm to show that the following sequence of functions is Cauchy?

Tags: normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I have a sequence of continuous functions, in the closed interval $[0,1]$, given by

$$f_n(t) =   \begin{cases}
       0 &\quad 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}\\
       n(t-\frac{1}{2}) &\quad \frac{1}{2} < t \leq \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{n}  \\
       1 &\quad \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{n} < t \leq 1 \\ 
     \end{cases}$$

The uniform norm for two such functions $f_i(t)$, for $n = i$, and  $f_j(t)$, for $n = j$ is given by

$$||f_i(t) - f_j(t)||_u = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f_i(t) - f_j(t)|$$

Now I would like to show that this sequence is Cauchy, using this norm specifically.

Assume $i > j$. Then in the interval $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{j}]$, $f_i$ will reach $1$ before $f_j$ because it has a steeper slope. $f_i$ reaches $1$ at $t = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{i}$ and $f_j(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{i}) = \frac{j}{i}$.

The maximum difference between the two functions then occurs at $t = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{i}$ and this is the uniform norm.

$||f_i(t) - f_j(t)||_u = |1 - \frac{j}{i} | = 1 - \frac{j}{i}$.

For this to be Cauchy then it has to be case that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there has to be a sufficiently large $N$ such that for every $i, j \geq N$ we have that $||f_i(t) - f_j(t)||_u < \epsilon$.

Now this can be accomplished if N is large and $i$ and $j$ are close together in value. However if you pick a specific $j* \geq N$ and let $i$ grow without bounds then you get

$\lim_{i \to \infty} 1-\frac{j*}{i} = 1$.

So for any $N$ we can find some $i,j \geq N$ such that $i >> j$ and the uniform norm is therefore not less than the chosen $\epsilon$. Therefor you cannot use the uniform norm to prove Cauchy.

Is there anything wrong in my reasoning here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sequence is not Cauchy in the uniform norm. Your arguement is correct but you can also prove it without making those computations. The point-wise limit is $0$ for $x <\frac  12$ and $1$ for $x >\frac 1 2 $ making the limiting function a discontinuous function. This implies that the sequence is not Cauchy (by completeness of $C[0,1]$).